# Creating string with specified length

Tags: php

I have an array with with data from the database, something like this:

```
array(4) { [0]=> string(9) "336_20235" [1]=> string(9) "336_20237" [2]=> string(9) "336_20239" [3]=> string(9) "336_20241" }
```

There are all elements from DB. I need to prepare string from this data, comma separated, but I have a limitation to 1000 signs. So I'm using explode function, and my string looks like this:

```
336_20235,336_20237,336_20239,336_20241
```

but when string lenght will be over 1000 signs, I need to split string, so I'm doing this:

```
(explode('|',(wordwrap(implode(', ', $mystring), 1000, '|', true))))
```

So now I have for example two arrays with strings,  like this:

```
[0]=> string(999) "3-9782, 3-9781, 3-9776, 3-9775, 3-9783, 3-9780, 3-9779, 3-9778, 3-9777, 1-9756, 4-9789,
```

As You can see, I have a space after comma. I don't need that space. I know I can do this:

```
str_replace(' ', '',(explode('|',(wordwrap(implode(', ', $mystring), 1000, '|', true)))));
```

After that string looks like this:

```
[0]=> string(887) "3-9782,3-9781,3-9776,3-9775,3-9783,3-9780,3-9779,3-9778,3-9777
```

So now the string have 887 signs, and it's ok, but It's about API calls, with limitation to 1000 signs and 200 calls in hour. So I could place more data from the array here, and limit the API calls, but wordwrap function needs space to properly slice elements.

I wonder if there is better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I've approached this is to try and split the string by the last comma before the 1000 character (defined in `$splitAt`).  So what it does is to first add them all together with comma separators.  Then look for the last comma in the first 1000 characters using [`strrpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php) (storing this in `$splitPos`).  Then extract the first part and store it in the output and carries on with the remaining string till there is nothing else to work with...

```
$long = implode(",", $source).",";
$splitAt = 1000;
$split = [];
while ( $long ) {
    $splitPos = strrpos(substr($long,0, $splitAt), ",");
    $split[] = substr($long, 0, $splitPos);
    $long = substr($long, $splitPos+1);
}
print_r($split);
```

Answer (score 0):

As i perceived you main problem is because when you are making string it comes with space after every comma, hence it consumes your string sign length.

So you can avoid this by just removing the space after comma in your implode function like:

```
implode(',', $mystring)  instead of `implode(', ', $mystring)`
```

Hope this works for you. Or let know if you have different problem.

As you mentioned, can you please tell me more where and what method you are using for Slicing as you mentioned
"wordwrap function needs space to properly slice elements."
As i can see, you are using simply explode function for slicing.
please clear.

Comment: Yes, I'm doing this, because after that I'm using wordwrap function, which puts a '|' when string is going to exceed the sign limit. This space prevent to do wordwrap function to slice element in half lenght: [0]=> string(887) "3-9782,3-9781,3-9776,3-97"  [1]=> string(500) "82,3-9781,3-9776,3-97"

Comment: then you can use solution suggestion by @Nigel Ren. It simple and perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression matching to limit the size of the strings:

```
$data = [234234, 35464564, 23436232, 6508482, 234892, 34534524323, 43453, 2412, 34534523];
$limit = 20;

// fill $matches[0] with the length-limited strings    
preg_match_all("/.{1,$limit}(?=,)/", implode(",", $data), $matches);

// this can leave leading or trailing commas, trim them off
array_walk($matches[0], function(&$v, $k){$v = trim($v, ",");});

var_dump($matches[0]);
```